# Overriding FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR in AWS SDK Java V2

Tags: java, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I have previously overridden `FUTURE_COMPLETION_EXECUTOR` with `Runnable::run` as I want to process the response on the calling thread, which has worked fine. Now, however, after upgrading to `2.2.0` the same configuration results in `ForkJoin.commonPool` handling the response. Does anyone know how to revert the behaviour to how it was using the new version?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue was but upgrading to the latest version fixed it.